# Copy text into another application

Tags: qt, winapi

I want to emulate a barcode reader and copy barcode content (text) from my application to another application.

I have just found a method to select application window an paste keyCode.
It works with F1 Key fine, but with another key not. (I have tried Tab and space) I think that, Focus is not in text area.

```
HWND mywindow = ::FindWindow(NULL, L"test.txt - Editor");
uint keyCode;
QString str;
SetForegroundWindow(mywindow);


keyCode = VK_F1; // F1 key

PostMessage(mywindow, WM_KEYDOWN, keyCode, 0); // key down
PostMessage(mywindow, WM_KEYUP, keyCode, 0); // key up
```

Comment: Use UI Automation to automate other programs

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). That text was published almost 15 years ago. 15 years is enough time to come to terms with this limitation.

Comment: If the content is text, you could use `SendMessage(WM_CHAR)` to the edit class window.

Comment: I don't understand your negativ vote. The question is not bad. I'm just a rookie with no winapi experience, please respect. thanks Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content is the text, you could use the [`SendMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) to send [`WM_CHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-char) to the target window.

Also note that the window should be the edit window or the other child window which need to get the `WM_CHAR`, use the Notepad as example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HWND hWndParent = FindWindowW(NULL, L"test.txt - Notepad");
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowExW(hWndParent, NULL, L"Edit", NULL);
    char str[] = "test_text";
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CHAR, str[i], 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, Drake! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad to help you.